# Convert large numbers to human-readable format with K,M,B suffixes in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Using BigQuery, I would like to transform (large) numbers into human-readable format (as you can do in spreadsheets using the formula described [here](https://medium.com/@brookinc/the-only-spreadsheet-custom-number-format-you-ll-ever-need-7cc356a7ca3e)).

Numbers in the thousands range should have a 'K' suffix, the millions an 'M' and the billions a 'B'. Ideally, the outputs would also have a dollar currency symbol in front.

Example inputs and outputs:

- 123 --> $123
- 1234 --> $1.2K
- 1234567 --> $1.2M
- 1234567890 --> $1.2B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **RANGE_BUCKET**,

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([123, 1234, 1234567, 12345678, 1234567890, 0, 999, 1000, 1000000]) num
)
SELECT COALESCE(
         FORMAT('$%.1f%s', SAFE_DIVIDE(num, ranges[SAFE_OFFSET(o)]), ['K', 'M', 'B'][SAFE_OFFSET(o)]),
         '$' || num
       ) AS shorts
  FROM sample_table,
UNNEST ([STRUCT([1000, 1000000, 1000000000, 1000000000000] AS ranges)]),
UNNEST ([RANGE_BUCKET(num, ranges) - 1]) o;
```

[image]

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#range_bucket

Answer (score 0):

I've also turned Jaytiger's correct answer into a temporary function and am sharing in case anyone wants to use it in that way:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  format_usd(x INT64)
  RETURNS string AS( COALESCE( FORMAT('$%.1f%s', SAFE_DIVIDE(x,
          [1000,
          1000000,
          1000000000,
          1000000000000][SAFE_OFFSET(RANGE_BUCKET(x,
              [1000,
              1000000,
              1000000000,
              1000000000000]) - 1)]), ['K', 'M', 'B'][SAFE_OFFSET(RANGE_BUCKET(x,
            [1000,
            1000000,
            1000000000,
            1000000000000]) - 1)]),
      '$' || x ));
```

I'm not super confident in my understanding of what's actually happening here (I'm a relative beginner) so please feel free to point out any mistakes or make any suggestions!